# How to align buttons to the center in horizontal panel?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a horizontal panel and 2, sometimes 3 buttons.

```
Button btn1 = new Button("Ok");
Button btn2 = new Button("Cancel");
HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
panel.setWidth(100%);
panel.add(btn1);
panel.add(btn2);
panel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

But only cancel button is in the center then. But how to align both...or even any number of buttons to the center on one horizontal panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place those buttons in a smaller panel, add that panel to the larger panel, and then align the smaller panel:

```
Button btn1 = new Button("Ok");
Button btn2 = new Button("Cancel");
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(btn1);
buttonPanel.add(btn2);
panel.add(buttonPanel);
panel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Comment: You can also look at MigLayout if you start to run into too many panels.